# Compile time validation for iterator usage?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, iterator, erase

I have the following piece of careless C++ code, which compiles without a hitch under VC10, but fails miserably during runtime. I am wondering if there is a way to validate this kind of error at compile time?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <set>

void minus(std::set<int>& lhs, const std::set<int>& rhs)
{
    for ( auto i = rhs.cbegin(); i != rhs.cend(); ++i )
    {
        lhs.erase(i); // !!! while I meant "*i" !!!
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int v_lhs[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    std::set<int> s_lhs(&v_lhs[0], &v_lhs[sizeof(v_lhs) / sizeof(int)]);

    int v_rhs[] = {1,3,5};
    std::set<int> s_rhs(&v_rhs[0], &v_rhs[sizeof(v_rhs) / sizeof(int)]);

    minus(s_lhs, s_rhs);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I am fully aware that C++11 (as partially adopted early by VC10) has corrected the behavior that 'erase" actually takes "const_iterator".

Thanks in advance for any valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is not a mind-reading language. All it knows are types. It knows that `erase` takes an iterator. And it knows that `i` is an iterator of the same type. Therefore, as far as the compiler's rules of C++ are concerned, it is legal to call `erase(i)`.

There's no way for the compiler to know what you *meant* to do. Nor is there a way for the compiler to know that the *contents* of `i` are not appropriate for this particular use of `erase`. Your best bet is to just try to avoid mistakes. Range-based `for` (or the use of `std::for_each`) would help you here, as both of these hide the iterator.

Comment: Right, it does seem that my best bet under this specific case is to be careful and possibly relying on some level of runtime check, e.g., turning on checked iterators during debugging, but this in turn relies on code coverage tests before shipping. Or uncovered code during development is always vulerable for bugs! Your point on avoiding iterators by leveraging for_each or range based for does have its merits for general container content manipulation (with modifying the container while iterating being a typical exception among some other special use cases).